# What wrong with my code to move a picturebox towards another picture box?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

PicTorpedo = a picturebox with a torpedo picture in it

PicSpaceObject1 = a picturebox with anything in it, doesn't matter

This is what i have... The right and left work, but up and down dont, what have I missed?

```
        'Torpedo Up
        If picTorpedo.Top < picSpaceObject1.Top - picSpaceObject1.Height Then
            picTorpedo.Top = picTorpedo.Top + 5
        End If

        'Torpedo Down
        If picTorpedo.Top - picTorpedo.Height < picSpaceObject1.Top Then
            picTorpedo.Top = picTorpedo.Top - 5
        End If

        'Torpedo Right
        If picTorpedo.Left + picTorpedo.Width < picSpaceObject1.Left Then
            picTorpedo.Left = picTorpedo.Left + 5
        End If

        'Torpedo Left
        If picTorpedo.Left > picSpaceObject1.Left + picSpaceObject1.Width Then
            picTorpedo.Left = picTorpedo.Left - 5
        End If
```

Comment: Firstly, don't change multiple position properties separately. Calculate the entire change you want to make and then do it in one go, by setting the `Location` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```vb
Dim dx = 0
Dim dy = 0

If picTorpedo.Left > picSpaceObject1.Right Then
    'The torpedo is after the object so move the torpedo left.
    dx = -5
ElseIf picTorpedo.Right < picSpaceObject1.Left Then
    'The torpedo is before the object so move the torpedo right.
    dx = 5
End If

If picTorpedo.Top > picSpaceObject1.Bottom Then
    'The torpedo is below the object so move the torpedo up.
    dy = -5
ElseIf picTorpedo.Bottom < picSpaceObject1.Top Then
    'The torpedo is above the object so move the torpedo down.
    dy = 5
End If

picTorpedo.Location = New Point(picTorpedo.Left + dx, picTorpedo.Top + dy)
```